# Where do Google plus and twitter app open links on Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview, google-plus, google-chrome-webview

When you click on a link in Twitter app or Google+ app on android, it opens in a chrome webview. Attaching a image. I dont know what its called and where can I find information about it and basic example.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it is called Chrome Custom Tabs.Check the link below [customtabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs)